# Netbeans suddenly doesn't stop at breakpoints

Tags: php, netbeans, breakpoints, xdebug

I have been working and debugging with NetBeans since almost a year with 0 problems. I even updated months ago my PHP version to 5.3.6 and Xdebug to v2.1.0 and worked fine.

Suddenly, NetBeans (6.9.1) is not stopping at breakpoints and I don't remember to have modified any configuration in php.ini or related stuff. The NetBeans option to "stop at first line" works and "xdebug_break();" works, too. Therefore I deduce Xdebug is correctly configured. I have tried in 3 different projects and it's unable to stop. The checkbox in the project properties "Copy files from sources folder to another location" is unchecked, so I don't think it is unable to locate the files.

My development machine is a Windows 7 64 bits Pro. Any suggestion about where I must look will be appreciated.

Comment: I've had a similar problem on Linux occasionally, and I'm pretty sure it's because Netbeans is failing to map a breakpoint to a browsed source file location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a lot of neurotic trying (I even tried to debug with Vim via Cygwin) now it works. I removed the projects, I created them again downloading them from the subversion repository and now they work again. Wasn't the first time I deleted and created them again from NetBeans, but it was the first time I also deleted the source's files. More bizarre than trying to parse HTML with regexp. Cthulhu knows...